# How should a weak_ptr be initialized in a class constructor that receives a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a class that receives a shared pointer in its constructor and stores it in a weak pointer but I'm not sure how (and where) to do this conversion.

```
class A {
    public:
        A(std::shared_ptr<B> Bptr);

    private:
        std::weak_ptr<B> m_Bptr;
};
```

Should I convert the `shared_ptr` before passing to the constructor or not?

Does passing the `shared_ptr` to the `weak_ptr` through an initialization list like this `A(std::shared_ptr<B> Bptr) : m_Bptr(Bptr) { }` works as expected or I need to explicitly convert in the body of the constructor?

Comment: Do you need to keep the object alive while the constructor runs? Why aren't you passing the `shared_ptr` by reference?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I wasn't focusing on this but there's no reason why I shouldn't pass it by reference. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template< class Y >
weak_ptr( const std::shared_ptr<Y>& r );
```

A constructor of `weak_ptr` takes a `shared_ptr` as argument. So, yes just passing the `shared_ptr` will work.

From cppreference:

> Constructs new weak_ptr which shares an object managed by r. If r
>   manages no object, *this manages no object too.